# Solana how to stake native SOL to a Rust program and withdraw SOL from a program?

Tags: rust, solana

I have Googled about this and only found how to send tokens via command line:

https://spl.solana.com/token

But I need to stake/withdraw Native SOL, not tokens, into/from Rust programs.

Also I found this about Rust native token:

https://docs.rs/solana-program/1.7.10/solana_program/native_token/index.html

https://docs.rs/solana-program/1.7.10/solana_program/native_token/struct.Sol.html

It seems I have to declare this Sol struct

```
pub struct Sol(pub u64);
```

Then use its "send" trait to send it... right?
Could somebody explain how to do this via Rust programs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap Sol into a wrapped sol Token via the SPL Token program. From there you can use the Wrapped SOL like any SPL Token. Here is a pretty good example

https://github.com/project-serum/serum-dex-ui/blob/5b4487634e3738c57ace6da1377704e95f53c588/src/pages/pools/PoolPage/PoolAdminPanel.tsx#L250-L272

```
const wrappedSolAccount = new Account();

transaction.add(
  SystemProgram.createAccount({
    fromPubkey: wallet.publicKey,
    lamports: parsedQuantity + 2.04e6,
    newAccountPubkey: wrappedSolAccount.publicKey,
    programId: TokenInstructions.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
    space: 165,
  }),
  TokenInstructions.initializeAccount({
    account: wrappedSolAccount.publicKey,
    mint: TokenInstructions.WRAPPED_SOL_MINT,
    owner: wallet.publicKey,
  }),
  TokenInstructions.transfer({
    source: wrappedSolAccount.publicKey,
    destination: vaultAddress,
    amount: parsedQuantity,
    owner: wallet.publicKey,
  }),
  TokenInstructions.closeAccount({
    source: wrappedSolAccount.publicKey,
    destination: walletTokenAccount.pubkey,
    owner: wallet.publicKey,
  }),
);
```

So essentially what it's doing here is

1. Create a random account where you can deposit some SOL into and deposit the amount required plus the rent amount (hence parsedQuantity + 2.04e6)
2. Use the token program to initialise the account as a WRAPPED_SOL_ACCOUNT
3. Transfer the wrapped SOL (or in your case, you may just want to call the program and put the wrapped SOL account as a parameter)
4. Close the Wrapped SOL account so that the user gets back their rent

Comment: Yes, I saw that but not sure if that is the correct way... quite complicated but I guess that is the only way to go for this. Thank you!

Comment: Hi yangli-io, would you be interested in a job for modifying Solana's SPL token program, so every transaction comes with a fee deducted from the sender?

Comment: @Russo, I'm honoured :D but sorry super busy at the moment

Comment: Hi yangli-io, do all wrapped SOL tokens have the same token address of TokenInstructions.WRAPPED_SOL_MINT, right? Therefore I can check if a token address is the same as TokenInstructions.WRAPPED_SOL_MINT, that token must be a wrapped SOL, is that correct?

Comment: After wrapping a new token, I have So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112 as the token mint acount. So that must be the same as TokenInstructions.WRAPPED_SOL_MINT, right?

Comment: Quote "Accounts containing wrapped SOL are associated with a specific Mint called the "Native Mint" using the public key So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112" 
 from https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/master/docs/src/token.md#wrapping-sol